# Batch - Echo does not display variable in loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, echo

I am doing some experiments to learn how works the batch script.

I have an issue with displaying some text in a loop

Here is my code :

```
 for  %%j in (C:\Users\*) do (
 SET _test=123456789abcdef0
  SET _result=%_test:~0,5%
 ECHO %_result%          =12345
 )
```

And the result is : 
                     =12345

If I use the following code :

```
 SET _test=123456789abcdef0
  SET _result=%_test:~0,5%
 ECHO %_result%          =12345
```

Then the result is 
 12345             =12345 as expected.

What is wrong with the loop here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

```
 setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
 for  %%j in (C:\Users\*) do (
 SET _test=123456789abcdef0
  SET _result=!_test:~0,5!
 ECHO !_result!          =12345
 )
```